# Is it possible for PDO::FETCH_OBJ to set the value of a null field to null instead of leaving the property undefined?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In a case where you:

1. Left Join a table as part of a query
2. And use `$W = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` to loop over the results
3. And have a field, `ColumnName`, with a null value because the join could not be made for the current row.

Then the property `$W->ColumnName` will be undefined.

Is there a PDO setting where a column that is null can have it's property defined as null in the fetched object?

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using PHPs standard class to retrieve values you can use an entity class as shown below.

```
Class customer {

    protected $_email;

    public function __construct(array $config = array()){
         $this->setOptions($config);
     }

    public function getEmail(){
        return $this->_email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email){
        $this->_email = $email;
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        $_classMethods = get_class_methods($this);
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
            if (in_array($method, $_classMethods)) {
                $this->$method($value);
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Invalid method name');
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function setOption($key, $value){
        return $this->setOptions(array($key, $value));
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do this.

```
$W = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$customer = new Customer($w);
```

And now accessing a property will return null or the default value set in the entity class. Even if its undefined in the query results.

```
$customer->getEmail();
```

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing, but if the field is null and thus, the property is undefined, you get `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::SomeField`. Does `FETCH_ASSOC` handle null values differently?

Comment: @Nick are you setting a default value for the null property in your StdClass?

Comment: *Can* you set default values for `StdClass`?

Comment: @Nick Yes. But you'll end up creating an entity class like the one above.

Comment: @Nick so you can create the entity class assign a default value or leave it blank for null, fetch records from database, assign them to entity class, validate data and use it.